# Select the group with highest display priority

Tags: mysql

Im having a problem making it select the group with the highest display priority.
The query is:

```
SELECT
    xf_user_group_relation.user_id, xf_user_field_value.field_value as custom_flags,
    xf_user_external_auth.provider_key,
    xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id,
    MAX( xf_user_group.display_style_priority ) AS display_style_priority,
    xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id IN(5,6,11,12) AS is_vip
FROM xf_user_group_relation
INNER JOIN xf_user_group
    ON xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id = xf_user_group.user_group_id
INNER JOIN xf_user_external_auth
    ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = xf_user_external_auth.user_id
LEFT JOIN xf_user_field_value
    ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = xf_user_field_value.user_id
    AND xf_user_field_value.field_id = 'gtarp_custom_flags'
WHERE
    xf_user_external_auth.provider = 'steam'
    AND xf_user_group.display_style_priority >= 1000
    AND xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id NOT IN(19,20)
GROUP BY
    xf_user_group_relation.user_id,
    xf_user_external_auth.provider_key
```

It seems it selects the group with the lowest id, which is not what I want. I want it to select the group with the highest display priority.

So user_group_id should be the group with the highest display priority i.e `MAX( xf_user_group.display_style_priority)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    xf_user_group_relation.user_id, xf_user_field_value.field_value as custom_flags,
    xf_user_external_auth.provider_key,
    xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id,
    MAX( xf_user_group.display_style_priority ) AS display_style_priority,
    xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id IN(5,6,11,12) AS is_vip
FROM xf_user_group_relation
INNER JOIN xf_user_group
    ON xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id = xf_user_group.user_group_id
INNER JOIN xf_user_external_auth
    ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = xf_user_external_auth.user_id
LEFT JOIN xf_user_field_value
    ON xf_user_group_relation.user_id = xf_user_field_value.user_id
    AND xf_user_field_value.field_id = 'gtarp_custom_flags'
WHERE
    xf_user_external_auth.provider = 'steam'
    AND xf_user_group.display_style_priority >= 1000
    AND xf_user_group_relation.user_group_id NOT IN(19,20)
GROUP BY
    xf_user_group.display_style_priority,
    xf_user_group_relation.user_id,
    xf_user_external_auth.provider_key
```

Comment: Each group the users are in is now shown, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Basically what you need to do is, when you are selecting `MAX()` for any table column, you need to make sure that table is in `GROUP BY` clause to make effect.